# New lines in a string with GD library

Tags: php, gd

Is it possible? \n doesnt work, html doesnt work, nothing seems to work. I know I could just make a new string instead, but that is more effort than should be needed for this simple task.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can't

you have to output a new string some pixels lower than the previous.

\n won't do a linebreak for you...

Comment: Darn. How could I find out the font height in pixels?

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert line breaks, you can get the bounding box of any truetype font by using the [imagettfbbox](https://www.php.net/imagettfbbox) function.

You might want to take a look at the comments on that page and the comments on the [imagettftext](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) function page, they might have the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment you can't.

However use something like this can be more convenient if you get a lot of lines:

```
$margin = 10;
$font-size = 25;
$top = 10;//y
$left = 10;//x

imagettftext($img, $font-size, 0, $left, $top, $black, './arial.ttf', 'line1');
imagettftext($img, $font-size, 0, $left, $top +($font-size + $margin']), $black, './arial.ttf', 'line2');
imagettftext($img, $font-size, 0, $left, $top +($font-size + $margin'])*2, $black, './arial.ttf', 'line3');
imagettftext($img, $font-size, 0, $left, $top +($font-size + $margin'])*3, $black, './arial.ttf', '...');
```

You can easily make a function to write multiple lines with this.